# Which is the best algorithm to use out of dincis algorithm and ford fulkerson to solve max flow problems?

Tags: algorithm

Out of these algorithms which will be the best efficient algorithm to solve max flow problems

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Some algorithms will have a better complexity for sparse graphs, other will run faster but with a bigger memory footprint, others will be slower in theory, but faster in practice, etc ....

Answer (score 4):

**Which is the best algorithm to use to solve max flow problems?**

**Answer is:** it depends...

Without any information about the graph you have:

- Ford–Fulkerson algorithm **O(f*E)**
- Edmonds–Karp algorithm **O(V*E^2)**
- Dinic's algorithm **O(V^2*E)** but very fast in practice

You must choose which one to use depending on the memory and time constraints of the problem.

V: the number of vertex in the graph

E: the number of edges in the graph

f: is the maximum flow in the graph

**Bipartite Graph**

Also, if it is a **bipartite graph** your implementation can be O(n*m)

n: the cardinality of set A

m: the cardinality of set B

**Competitive Programming:**

In competitive programming **Dinic's algorithm** is one of the most useful because is very fast in practice. Many of the problems I solved were using Dinic. Although if the restrictions of the problem are not strong implement **Ford–Fulkerson** algorithm or **Edmonds–Karp algorithm** is faster than Dinic's algorithm (the time of coding is important too)

Comment: Have you implemented Dinic's with Link-Cut Tree data structure?